# How to observe when a custom object changes even after it's extended

Tags: java, inheritance, field, onchange, listeners

So let's say I have a custom object in java:

```
   public class TestObject {

    private int value = 0;

        public TestObject(int value) {
                this.value = value;
        }

    public void increaseValue() {
        value++;
    }

    }
```

Now I want to know when this object is modified.  Or more specifically, I want to know when any of it's fields have changed (in this case value).  Furthermore, if I extend TestObject, I still want to be able to listen to any field changes that might happen to that object, including if that change is to a new field new fields.

I've done some research and found of variety of listeners that come with java, but they all seem to fail in the area that they require you to put calls to the listeners at the end of you're methods.  For example, increaseValue() would also have to notify all of the listeners to the TestObject that value had changed.  Obviously this doesn't work for me because extensibility is a must have and I do not know that if people who inherit from that object will adhere to the requirement that they must notify listeners.  Not to mention, it seems like a pain to have to program that for each mutator method

If any light could be shed on this subject it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [approach that Hibernate uses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391989/how-does-hibernate-create-proxies-of-concrete-classes) i.e. instrument/proxy your classes to add additional (listener) logic around your POJOs' getters and setters. But then you need to ensure that all use only proxied classes.

Comment: See my response -- a production aspect would solve the problem of having to use proxies.

Comment: While this looks like a potentially complicated solution, it is most in line with what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

> Not to mention, it seems like a pain to have to program that for each
>   mutator method

Take a look at [The AspectJ Project](http://eclipse.org/aspectj/). You could achieve this very easily with production aspect using a [pointcut for field assignment](http://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/quick.html#quick-pointcuts).

```
public privileged aspect TestObjectObserver {
    before(Object o) : set(* TestObject.*) && args(o) {
      // notify listeners
    }
} 

// runs before field assignment to any field of TestObject. The value to be
// assigned is converted to an object type (int to Integer, for
// example) and named o in the body

// the aspect needs to be declared privileged so access private fields
```

Comment: See @Andrey Adamovich's response - proxies would solve the problem of having to use AspectJ ... :-)

Answer (score 1):

> Obviously this doesn't work for me because extensibility is a must
>   have and I do not know that if people who inherit from that object
>   will adhere to the requirement that they must notify listeners

Your approach is not in the correct path.

You can not enforce a derived class to keep the base's class invariants since inheritance can allow descendant classes to alter implementation in a way that makes them invalid from the viewpoint of the parent class.

In your case the derived class MAY or MAY not call the notification upon modification.

In cases like this you should model arround `Composition` and not `Inheritence`
[Composition vs Inheritence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

For your example:

```
class Value{    
    private int value;   
     public void increaseValue() {  
            value++;  
     }  
}
```

Value knows how to increment itself.

```
class ValueHolder extends Observable {  
       private Value theValue;  
       public ValueHolder(Value v){  
          theValue = v;  
       }
       public void modifyValue(String methodName)(){  
           Method method = theValue.getClass().getMethod(methodName, null);  
           method.invoke(theValue,null);//Since it has no args           
           setChanged();  
           notifyObservers();  
       }  
    }
```

So all the code will be as follows:

```
ValueHolder vh = new ValueHolder(new Value(10));  
//registration of listeners
vh.modifyValue("increaseValue");  

//So if you extend the Value 
class DerivedValue extends Value{    
    private int y;   
     public void increaseY() {  
            y++;  
     }  
}  

ValueHolder vh = new ValueHolder(new DerivedValue());  
//registration of listeners
vh.modifyValue("increaseY);
```

So the catch now is that the usage of the objects are via the holder.
Then the notification will happen.

Comment: This is not correct. The idea behind inheritance is that derived class needs to obey base class's invariants. That is the entire point of LSP, isn't it? Specifically base class method's invariants are the type pf parameters, type of return value and exceptions. The problem here is that base class wants to force invariants on derived class.

Comment: Yes you are right.It is the programmers responsibility to enforce the invariants.I agree.This is what I am also saying here. It is not possible to enforce the invariants of the base class.

Comment: No, it is not programmers' responsibility to enforce invariants, the language does not let you break the invariants. That argument breaks down with `UnsupportedOperationException` but in theory the idea is that sub-classes will not be able to break the super class invariants.

Comment: @Hemal:I am not sure we are talking about the same thing.If for example in base class the condition `a < b` should remain valid in all cases  (`a` and `b` be member fields) how can you make sure that the programmer extending the class and overriding the methods preserves this invariant? You can't.This is my point here

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm a little confused.  Could you guys perhaps provide me with a little more direction of what I should research?

Comment: @Zargoon:As mentioned in the answer, inheritence does not guarantee what you want I.e. you can not guarantee that the derived classes follow the base's class behavior of notifying listeners.You should look into composition instead and also reflection.I have gave you a small example to understand what I am taking about.In this example the `Value` class which is your original `TestObject` can be extended as fit without needing to worry about notification.The caveat is that the class  must be manipulated only via the `Holder` class passing the method name to call.The holder notifies all listeners

Comment: I don't see how this helps, it just shifts the responsibility from `Value` to `ValueHolder`, with the added baggage of reflection and loss of compile time checking.

Comment: Well it is just the first thing that came to my mind that seems to help in his case.It indeed shifts the responsibility from `Value` to `ValueHolder` and I mentioned that to the answer, but now he doesn't need to care about the implementation of derived classes of `Value`.May be there are better approaches. I do not know `AspectJ` to understand your suggestion, but it is a starting point for OP