# Is it possible to work with huge connected graph with Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, graph, persistence

Suppose I have connected graph described in database with many-to-many relationship. Each database row is reflected onto `Node` class with `Linked` property, which points to all other linked nodes.

If I `load()` any node from database, will Hibernate load cascadely all other nodes into memory? If not then how it will fill `Linked` property pointing to not loaded nodes?

Comment: What have you tried? What behaviour have you seen from Hibernate so far? Why are you unable to store what you describe?

Answer (score 0):

The [load javadoc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#load%28java.lang.Class,%20java.io.Serializable%29) says:

> Return the persistent instance of the given entity class with the
>   given identifier, assuming that the instance exists. This method might
>   return a proxied instance that is initialized on-demand, when a
>   non-identifier method is accessed.

Hibernate (if not specified otherwise) will lazy-load instances and proxy them so when you try to access a field then the proxy will get the value from your database.

In your particular case the Linked property will be pointing mostly to a proxy that will have lazy loaded properties too. Hibernate makes this to not to load your entire database in one query (or in this case, your load method).

Comment: How is it possible? How Hibernate can intercept my access to an object and load it on the fly? Suppose I loaded `Node node1`. Suppose it is connected with 10 other nodes. Suppose I am calling `node1.getLinked().size()`, what it will return?

Comment: Proxies. You may want to check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391989/how-does-hibernate-create-proxies-of-concrete-classes)

Comment: It will return whatever you expect to return, remember, the object references are ok but the actual objects referenced are proxies.

Comment: Okay, so it will return 10. Going further. What it will return if I take one of them? For example with `node1.getLinked().iterator().next()`? This will be a proxy object? Okay suppose it has some public `int` field and I am accessing it. Will it feel my access and load my oblect? How???

Comment: So, you mean it interferes bytecode somehow??? It can intercept my object access with `javassist` magic? But why then need I use `load()` and `save()` at all?

Comment: Javassist says this:
_Javassist (Java Programming Assistant) makes Java bytecode manipulation simple. It is a class library for editing bytecodes in Java; it enables Java programs to define a new class at runtime and to modify a class file when the JVM loads it._ It can do many things  i guess. As for your int field I may say yes but I cannot tell exactly how.

Comment: *AJEM* Stacky says Please avoid extended discussions in comments. So if you have questions on javassist better ask them in other question...

Comment: I need definite knowledge. I don't believe it can intercept my POJO access. Possible some code is needed to work with proxies, so the question is still opened.

Comment: Thank you very much for your recommendations! :)